# In Ruby, how do I split a range into chunks for batch operations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This should be a fun little puzzle for all you Ruby golfers and gymnasts.

The problem: I have millions of SQL database records that I need to move over to a NoSql database in batches of maybe 1000 or so, in reverse ID order (so find_each isn't a valid solution).

This will run on a small server so I don't want to keep all the IDs in memory at once, just the IDs for one chunk.

I'm hoping to use something along these lines in my codebase:

```
chunkify max_id, step_size do |ids|
  copy_to_nosql SqlTable.where(id: ids)
end
```

Can you write `chunkify`?

The solution should not repeat any IDs, it should cover all IDs, the first yielded array should contain max_id and the lowest ID returned should be 1.

PS. I am using the Rails framework, so feel free to use Rails specific language augmentations.

PPS. I don't want to use database-driven solutions like 'limit' and 'offset', as for my database implementation at least, queries take longer to process as the offset increases.

EDIT

Here's a working solution. Any alternatives improving on readability, terseness or efficiency are most welcome:

```
  # yields arrays of ints (chunks), of [chunk_size] or lower length, which,
  # when added together, would cover all values from 0 to [top_value], exactly
  # once each. The highest value 'chunk' is provided first.
  #
  # > chunkify(100, 10) { |chunk| puts chunk.inspect }
  # [91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]
  # [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90]
  # ...
  # [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
  # => 100
  # > chunkify(27, 8) { |chunk| puts chunk.inspect }
  # [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]
  # [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
  # [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
  # [1, 2, 3]
  # => 27
  def chunkify(top_value, chunk_size)
    top_value.step(1, -chunk_size) do |i|
      yield ((i-chunk_size > 0 ? i-chunk_size+1 : 1)...i+1).to_a
    end
  end
```

Comment: Have a look at the find_each method http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_each

Comment: Find_each locks you into ascending ID values.

Comment: Why the reverse order?

Comment: How about `User.order(id: :desc).find_each`?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: To minimise disruption to live data. Recent IDs are exponentially more likely to need to be accessed based on the architecture of the site.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: find_each forces an ascending ID order. I think it also uses 'limit' and 'offset' behind the scenes, so it slows down over time for the kind of database sizes I'm talking about.

Comment: Anyhow, writing `chunkify` is almost trivial. You didn't give it a try, did you?

Comment: Almost, but not quite, trivial. I have a solution, but I thought it would make a fun SO problem. And I usually end up learning some language or framework trick in the process.

Comment: If you have a solution post it, this is always better to show that at least you tried. And it helps people to understand what you really try to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something as simple as this?

```
def chunkify(max_val,chunk_size);
  max_val.downto(1).each_slice(chunk_size) {|chunk| yield chunk.reverse }
end 

chunkify(100,10) {|c| puts c.inspect }
  #[91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]
  #[81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90]
  #[71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80]
  #[61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70]
  #[51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60]
  #[41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]
  #[31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]
  #[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
  #[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
  #[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
  #=> nil
```

as @SergioTulentsev pointed out this seems trivial.

Also reverse will be less efficient and equally as effective as in decrementing order because SQL does not care about the order for an `IN()` clause.

Comment: Good answer. You are correct about the 0 of course, that was a typo. Corrected.

Comment: @AFaderDarkly as a note this method is faster than your current approach as well because currently you are creating a new range using conditionals that must be evaluated and then converting it to an Array on every iteration.

Comment: Yes, this is good. I'd rejected each_slice as I suspected it would require an array, but of course it's just iterating through the enumerator so it won't try and keep all IDs in memory.

Comment: It is indeed faster. Benchmark has it running in significantly less than half the time. Sold, have a green tick. The solution may have been trivial, but I definitely learned something from the process of asking and your answer. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord provides a [`find_each`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each) method you can use to load small batches of records and perform a specific operation on the result set.

> Looping through a collection of records from the database (using the all method, for example) is very inefficient since it will try to instantiate all the objects at once.
>
> In that case, batch processing methods allow you to work with the records in batches, thereby greatly reducing memory consumption.
>
> The `find_each` method uses `find_in_batches` with a batch size of `1000` (or as specified by the `:batch_size` option).

You may want to add a new boolean field to the column you have to migrate to make sure you filter out the query to just the record where `processed` is false. In this way, even if the process dies for some reason, you can resume it and it will not restart from the beginning.

Comment: find_each locks you into ascending ID values.

Comment: find_each should work with sorts; there's no reason it shouldn't.

Comment: Should. Doesn't. The reasoning is that anything other than the PK (for example, created_at dates) may not be unique, so you could get duplicates and/or missing values when reading batches. (And who would ever want to go in REVERSE order?) My solution to this would be to use ID as a secondary ordering field, ensuring consistency across pages.

Comment: @AFaderDarkly Didn't you basically just say you want to go in reverse order? You want to start with the chunk with the highest ids, right? So `order(id: :desc).find_each`. I don't see the problem.

Comment: @Ajedi32: I think what he's saying is that `find_each` ignores that reverse order on `id`. Would've tested this, but I don't have an sql database lying around :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Ah, found it: "NOTE: It's not possible to set the order. That is automatically set to ascending on the primary key (“id ASC”) to make the batch ordering work. This also means that this method only works with integer-based primary keys." So yeah, if order is important I guess this won't work.

Comment: Indeed. ```find_each``` defers to ```find_in_batches``` which does this: 
  ```if logger && (arel.orders.present? || arel.taken.present?)```
    ```logger.warn("Scoped order and limit are ignored, it's forced to be batch order and batch size")```
  ```end```

  ```relation = relation.reorder(batch_order).limit(batch_size)```